# Save a graph from PHP Spreadsheet to PHP Word

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

Good day!

I created a graph on PHP Spreadsheet using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Chart\Chart.
Is there any way I can use/convert/ember/export this graph so that I can add it to a word doc programmatically?